# How to update objects in document's array (mongodb)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Assume I have the following document:

```js
{
  name: 'any-name',
  array: [
    { _id: 'any-id', a: 'any-a-data', b: 'any-b-data', c: 'any-c-data' },
    ...more objects
  ]
}
```

I want to call updateOne method and update the entire object in array with _id = 'any-id' with the folowing object

```html
{ a: 'new-a-data', b: 'new-b-data', c: 'new-c-data' }
```

so the result will be:

```js
{
  name: 'any-name',
  array: [
    { _id: 'any-id', a: 'new-a-data', b: 'new-b-data', c: 'new-c-data' },
    ...more objects
  ]
}
```

I trying something like:

```html
model.updateOne(
      { 'array._id': _id }, 
      { $set: { 'array.$': data } }
    )
```

data = { a: 'new-a-data', b: 'new-b-data', c: 'new-c-data' }

can someone help me?

Comment: Are you using express ?

Comment: yes, I am using express

Comment: The answer didn’t work ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the new data before updating the document:

```
var { newA } = data;

Model.findOneAndUpdate({ 'array._id': 'any-id' }, {
    '$set': {
        'array.$.a': newA
    }
})
.then((data) => { console.log(data); res.redirect('/') })
.catch((err) => res.status(500).send("Error: ", err));
```

Comment: this answer partially works. I want to update only the new values, for example if I don't have "newA" value, "array.$.a" will be null

Comment: Try findOneAndUpdate instead of updateOne and it should work.